# Cassandra - iterate over all Row Keys without duplicates on random partitioner

Tags: cassandra

`get_range_slices` iterates over all keys also in case of random partitioner. As I understand result of this query will not return duplicated keys, because it goes ascending over ring. Since keys are hashed, Cassandra would need additional "index" to be able to execute such query - like each key would need to keep references to next key (which is not the case).

Could someone give me some hints on how Cassandra realizes iteration over all keys in case of random partitioner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results are returned in random order. Or more specifically, token order (the hashed value of the keys).

Comment: but how does it work internally? For example: each SSTable has file which contains sorted row keys. In order to skipp duplicates Cassandra would need to merge-sort all row keys from all SSTables - this would work, but it's not peformant

Comment: You've answered your own question. It is not performant. That being said, Cassandra only needs to merge rows from sstables that overlap the bounds specified in the token range. Also, the api takes a column slice which Cassandra can use to check if there is any relevant data in each row before reading.

Comment: Row keys must be sorted in sstable by their hashed value - now all makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am not sure I understood the original question as if you have 100 nodes, you would never from a single node want to run get_range_slices.  Typically you would install hadoop map/reduce on top of cassandra with cassandra's adapter so you can process all keys in parallel.

get_range_slices in general is never used for getting "all" the keys on random partitioner.  Instead, map/reduce is utilized as it is MUCH MUCH faster to send your binary code to each machine and each machine executes in parallel so you can traverse the entire data set much much faster.

ie. maybe you need to look into map/reduce instead of get_range_slices?

Another option is PlayOrm's partitioning if you use PlayOrm since you can use storm and you can have a machine processing each partition.  AND you can do a

```
 PARTITIONS(:partitionId) SELECT * FROM Table
```

to get all the rows for a partition.

You can of course do joins and such too and they are fast as they read from multiple disks in parallel and dealing with disks, you want that parallel action to speed things up.

Comment: not get_range_slices? what command would it be? I do not understand why would I need to use distributed map-reduce, because sort-merge operation is always local. Kyes iterator walks over ring clockwise, and it operates always on single host. Local merge sort could use fork-join to execute sorting in parallel, what actually is great idea :)

Comment: sort-merge?  what are you talking about(I am confused by your comment)?  map/reduce is a way to deliver code to the data and that code can run on every row and you do whatever you want with it.  One example happens to be the terabyte sort benchmark, but tons of people are NOT using it to sort stuff....there are people who are sorting stuff sometimes.  Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Read my question, answer it, or delete pointless answer. Cassandra DOES NOT use map reduce to iterate over keys, so what you sre talking about?

Comment: you can setup hadoop map/reduce on cassandra to iterate over all keys in a column family.  It is way faster than doing get_range_slices....sorry you are so frustrated.  If you have 100 nodes, you really don't want to be using get_range_slice to process all rows is all I was tyring to say..you want to map/reduce with hadoop on cassandra(there is  word count example of this as well for map/reduce on cassandra).

Comment: I am using hadoop - but hadoop integration uses get_range_slices - this collects keys form single node

Comment: my bad, it's been a while, thought you were using a client.